# IdentityServer4 and ErrorMessage Cookie

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, identityserver4

I'm currently trying to implement IdentityServer4 to protect my API for an AngularJS 1.5 application using Azure Active Directory Crendentials.
So far it doesn't work and I'd like to  investigate.
In the http response I get a cookie with an error message encoded in some form. I've tried to  base64 decode it without success and I've been looking in the doc to understand what I should do with it, didn't find anything. 
So the question is : how can I get a human understandable message from that?
Here is what it looks like

```
cookie:ErrorMessage.e5742c4e5414ab10614d79a3719775cc=CfDJ8M80lOqHw6FIvMiD9FvqmP6iVMyvAU6sHsPcbnmfFfRCFlq-PsSJvnEMlYZBrAsjqxFM9TBQClOuz9LjsyFmCfosPf9hFHUMvnHRXLN_DRXbnUvzEhatZO6GYQpfHcxlponK-4gtYUDXerZjVQz6YZiHbSPisTFmlLJTLa0-d2jrUGaQYZU456pxEnBe_jTdWjLzSKwP35z8Kd2aCMYv6iaOX2Fae01hqwgnDQHSBNyyz5uQ_fKxUg-ILI8ev0pe5xOppBZE2dA-Zp_WGYXJbHK4shxTtzi1WGIeOkOv_IOk; access_token=CfDJ8M80lOqHw6FIvMiD9FvqmP4IGJjkVW5oI3tqfqBxruMH0bptGzZF3QZql8nEzK1iglB4xjkTswbQG-EajSZdtCebZ_Ur-8PvsYJpZBgN0mcjwccyJZuPb7Dkhi1vjVUEtxn_SxZ7rM8o4sQiea0-y2M61e8RxxkOlIybLJl_KLbLgeu80ZFSgpDbVeMPeN2LJV7HTzHbLGQG3D7LO0qlSsCl0OOMpk7ijJqOSmS-deE4BXxyZLe-atSmTEih7n6BK9jnodQbuYMEkv7TQzI9Z9QQlCTzY8p6hYTDR3gQF_5QAlP21_fzXkz7FEI32VHyOF13tkzPr2xiw5nkbxdVP3v9cMMYfxqQMVi8mV0xihCKZWbRbbtm65aKsGxcR1uru88q21p6YhBYh_utlOhe4ipA5pmA7o0x1yoSGk36GZtadDjpGOSUhzTbykODLrKFqvxKofBoyL-rOAU78LRxhOR0Xo6H3NijVy45h6_XHftYs9rmsflDsoitTzogRIMmn9kFaaBDJo02QEDWWf2mcrKDOUd0Ej1An8uXLmUR4yNrYZTdrEdlL9G3G3yMlf0DP6AFbONWL9JMY9Y8JzTlyeLmTay2jgMayb8JARi5AG27VS687rD2YEe2P3py3pCUaLvFdc939EmGXa3YUZCtc3FoFOgSJt5FMs0N_6k6EST9bO5w4vCdmlNqO8QYzgLtBDbIAPqVzZharJv9tdy1kyk8ZB0nSILvAx1Lv4D1LPD7LOZe7beJLTov_AF0pmPJvpIH01F8t7DmPnjABFX01mtd7jySKdw35pGuF8_zHY4kHt8rFPbB1Qpjj5VoFvDLvfL6TfEZ46xCBENr6aftAR6vDee1smoIgkIKm-JEeNeT9vN4Gjn02sCNeFYAxD61ZGGI73jNmeOPklnbwA6vxKYavk7A9GKbcbaIv8JDkgIr0CCOsWunIJNNQiMM34tq_dVs13t2nYYKEAqdJqlplV9Dq3GqUQ31RFdtWg0Pmt2xogY3vjlCTnr8Jxr7ZOnPBL9dvTArodQVHsu9EKIwCi8kIRMOO8OheLbPEVfuyOWot3n5uw7CzZ7eB-1QjkKSgDeNHrFrxi8fI1hBychEloR_rykaA2otK7dpzTb6y8d3RnsqCzz2Y5BLRAzef4foThFZrcWSvhuWhzgg5OOsoP0qAuk4ujWju7SY1vetrXmbF16LSeBk_MIRsCjImH95A9RhyRgSsL2kmTcen5m_RoOHkr5xezSIjoDr2MhdJ-jnDEO8hV8SpdRzIpU-zXOHf3NrRsU55NGxg_Fk9_Ypxj6AKBX08V48lkyZo5MPXxflWNsO6N2azyGWQUiprDriQioek2HrDBu36ARiaAEtRxq918vByYbtbD-3qNqpqYePIDLBpddiS1HwbSU8sPSYQSwNMqewU32pfat4P8m2QJr_aUK4tQpD1vnmeltz1HNFAQesBN4e-bFWSQBF7Nk6RjoOVzErtH5BVyXHpuSCdOGSvNsczYRqVFl2jzJ6MppKGGfag-WPaisFbVr-uPspLJ2PFSMgRNsx-HRrax0WbxkMKdHAL2Q0-jt77pCdHUmMwqyoy-RHkRRC3osfPGyLyq37HSoGmf9Oct56uzSGUK92zK0mKT33CRjMFAGJyu0R4jMeSPINAh4MfgW9bGaqfr8QM24-W3meK5K4VMsB_3Rse_kRlzpsgciZXtkYlUlm2Ff8Na0g6lAAFH70gQ7WF8faPdB8cJrR2shYQUsL57cYsXe6un6yZF8IVTPlIv4ANepst0xdoZYD1fa_bywASqePkLVDf1Gj0xZw5BDqjrz2kGS52Ytj52y0XO5rMBL0R5D-uc-7n_CnO_ksf2CEeNrQf2GfZc94_Zr9Lc4FIr29cW8pKOVyvj5a9Fe6vqMJFXRNUmjBp6Oq7CyLwx3MNep1bZIoc1w44eyqtyCD0SZB-3uXeFsm-ODkHJYbCGF0n-EVL81J8FMmwOztqyu4bUcpAWxulM1NRGyngxTB4Lis_1jcP6IAtddZOLEXlLSB-PN0vM02o10H4oOArBi4beNhnW5GZTmRRkJh6ZmOnNdHA-NMyhFZhjl91K040anX_r4ZpAatg-GUR17BxhWxDNcAh5dWXYCreSWtOUKE-6Y5qrjQIfLgEAJZITLERNswuDevU8SnDGNamvWoNKJbAMCQfPcdZ14aIVkrNiZakuJJVn478ZHV9ATUB33xXAo5o95qGeOsR8rNd-84Y9K3lhXhg-bEi0I65vhmjKCQ6rpXwOKiKinD9_V3CcUGEmCjjslNMQqhfd17Jbn6LxuDfVPVwX9AKXZxo2MFr_E8ETY0cWH08pzsnFwUqnOY9MVWPjoZB-v6NdGOCUeBF_iLJ8pvCOK4RqLTyaqyJrm43F4fbbiNnXuk8GWWcqPSpGEm_0xD-NEjtBj2I7pERapMX2n3DOKlVeeGJe-LlSHIK4W5LvPowc46XDir6VbId17at1xGgFL0oNCx1i1VDnwm7QMvgjwJjiqdd4N-N8IfjR-QqweBg_yS7c5diDg41VwfSs2BmsXuZdS8_uRJG1u5_S4cPqhXxyYISn5iQNRneL0xaPPbNfaw4H3zChM6yY8nWgWnyziMtiEhYsgPXhnNI-4d9GCw-qqfg9u00x_S0O0eR9s9cBlqyQZ4lhGGjPAclbS1Q7QWE-lOdUpG1tAtpM3Pg5ItrfCyfX8xv5gNMU7RHyE7uKUTUT7kevcwh0QyftXTBjBdfddTfxGgWJAb3PM-YcU_2Tgp4jWpkS45UMCxeswcz4nWmEmNXuhtYlLoOcOZsCJNRySRBVTcoWW8CMAsGrJ8xk4ZzjoKwR-psEBFklYOtCT-AOx6ji_Zmkn-SzZMmUQ22po7ZxwgD8Mdtu7jEVO0zIsx2-NuMaghvHWnAHA35pT64Q6fPO2WGVqv1mFzq_A1fVoNZVc7O-QVs3iync5XVELlHOh5o9kBvKS9tNed7IOV-erRhzOZ36GOxe5H0Jd0VhmBGMWA2sQ8ePn8iaXtOA4LRI3DdX9Cf0-qFNQF5Gbf369-QYJbwY83xFqeE_A8LY4TF4gggswsCBz1T6xvzKBDo4KhXBAUzleXvpwHZGYkP8cslLk8AkwjXdwFohJZbXWnKpykmjmZEV0r6dBK7xtaIdqUFhEFK9I
```

Comment: I've also tried to take the part after the = and paste it in jwt.io decoder, without success

Comment: Why don't you enable log and try to see actual error?

Comment: I have access to the console output which gives some level of information. My concern was more to see if i could get more/different information from that.